# Adding a string to comboBox

Tags: java, string, combobox, serial-port

I started working on a GUI, the first thing I wanted to do is to see which serial ports are active/connected. This is done by the `listSerialPorts()` function. I would like to put this information into a ComboBox. But it seems not to know the 'comboBox' variable when I try to use it in the function. What is the best way to fill the combobox from my function?

For the combobox: I just drag & dropped it. So all this other code has been generated automatically.
Does it matter where I put the function (before/after main)?
Btw. I don't have much experience with java.

```
public class gui_v1 {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    /** My input */
    public static String[] listSerialPorts() {
        Enumeration ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        ArrayList portList = new ArrayList();
        String portArray[] = null;
        while (ports.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier port = (CommPortIdentifier) ports.nextElement();
            if (port.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
                portList.add(port.getName());
            }
        }
        portArray = (String[]) portList.toArray(new String[0]);
        return portArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    gui_v1 window = new gui_v1();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public gui_v1() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    public void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setBounds(36, 49, 53, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you declare comboBox as variable local to the method initialize(). That makes it visible only in the method where comboBox is declared.

To make a variable accessible anywhere you could declare it as a static member of the class.

```
public class gui_v1
{
    private JFrame frame;
    public static JComboBox comboBox;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    /**
     * My input
     */
    public static String[] listSerialPorts()
    {
        Enumeration ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        ArrayList portList = new ArrayList();
        String portArray[] = null;
        while (ports.hasMoreElements())
        {
            CommPortIdentifier port = (CommPortIdentifier) ports.nextElement();
            if (port.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
            {
                portList.add(port.getName());
            }
        }
        portArray = (String[]) portList.toArray(new String[0]);
        return portArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    gui_v1 window = new gui_v1();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public gui_v1()
    {
        initialize();
        //comboBox is accessible from here too
        comboBox.setBounds(36, 49, 53, 20);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    public void initialize()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        //This uses a static member comboBox, initializes it with a value.
        //See declaration of member above : public static ComboBox comboBox 
        comboBox = new JComboBox();

        comboBox.setBounds(36, 49, 53, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);

    }
}
```